# Problem with bookmarking more than one file uploaded in rshiny

Tags: r

When I book mark my app , I can't find in the folder "shiny/bookmark" the two files uploaded. Only the last one were registered. Is it possible to manage this issue through my code
here is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tools)
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv"
                  )
        ),
        fileInput("file2", "Choose CSV File", multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv"
                  )
        ),
        tags$hr(),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        bookmarkButton()
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents"),
        tableOutput("content")
      )
    )
  )
}
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    if (nrow(inFile) == 1) {
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    } else {
      data.frame(x = "multiple files")
    }
  })
  
  output$content <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file2
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    if (nrow(inFile) == 1) {
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
      
    } else {
      data.frame(x = "multiple files")
    }
    
  })
  
}
enableBookmarking("server")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It seems according to this page **https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-bookmarking-doesnt-work-with-two-fileinputs-on-same-page/5847/5**
we need to change something like
**filename <- file.path(.dir, paste0(as.character(createUniqueId(8)), maybeGetExtension(fileBasename)))**

I don't know where to do this modification ,
May anyone help me please
May you give the explanation and maybe give the good code

Comment: You would need to update the Shiny function `fileupload.R`, so you have to create your own version of the shiny package. You can do this by forking shiny on github, make the change in `fileupload.R` and then install your version of shiny with `devtools::install_github`. However, this is a bit inconvenient, because you can't work with the CRAN released shiny version anymore. The bugfix is assigned for version 1.5, see the [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2754)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I indeed hope for a fix within the the Shiny master branch soon. Awaiting that, here is my solution:
**Do use the `onBookmark()`/`onRestore()` for those 2 data store within the .csv file** (if you are also interested by the *.csv file themselves then you should write them by yourself through `write.csv()`).

Below a minimal reproductible example with 2 dummy *.csv files (create your own to test). Their content is well restaured within the UI after bookmarking. However, I did have to use the double assignment "`<<-`" to force the `renderTable()` to refresh, not sure why.

You will notice that Shiny now creates a `values.rds` file within "shiny_bookmarks/your_state_id".

```
require(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {  
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(        
        fileInput("file1", "Choose first CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv")
        ),
        tags$hr(),        
        fileInput("file2", "Choose 2nd CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv")
        ),        
        bookmarkButton()
      ),      
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents1"),        
        tags$hr(),        
        tableOutput("contents2")
      )
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # We retrieve data
  data1 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(inFile)) # I copy/paste the help text but here you may want to use validate / need instead
      return(NULL)
    read.csv2(inFile$datapath)
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file2 
    if(is.null(inFile)) # same here
      return(NULL)
    read.csv2(inFile$datapath)
  })
  
  # Display data
  output$contents1 <- renderTable(data1())
  output$contents2 <- renderTable(data2())
  
  # BOOKMARKING *.CSV MANAGEMENT
  # Source : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html
  onBookmark(function(state) {
    print(state) # you may want to have a look to this variable
    state$values$data1_backup <- data1()
    state$values$data2_backup <- data2()
  })
  
  # Read values from state$values when we restore
  onRestore(function(state) {
    print(state$values$data1_backup) # to show you that former data are indeed stored here, after that you do want ever you want with
    print(state$values$data2_backup)
    
    data1 <<- reactive(state$values$data1_backup) # Double assignment request to force reactivty, not sure why
    data2 <<- reactive(state$values$data2_backup)
  })
  
  setBookmarkExclude(c("file1","file2")) # To avoid on restoration your data1() and data2() reactive container beeing re-executed and thus overwritten with wrong data
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

[edit] Img proof
[image]